# Getting the key from a huge list of key-value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, performance, data-structures

There is huge object which looks like:

```
{
  "exercise": ["running","walking","gym" ........lots of words],
  "eat": ["breakfast","dinner",....... lots of words..],
  .
  .
  .
  "lots of keys": [ .... ....]
}
```

There is a large amount of data categorized as shown above. On encountering a word like `gym` I need to find its category which is `exercise` in the above example. The brute-force approach of double looping will poorly solve the problem because the data is huge.

What algorithm could be applied here? What could data structure effectively solve this problem?

There will be a gradual increase in the volume of keys and items in each list, but it will easily surpass a million count of keys and the list containing the items.

**PS: I am perfectly okay with converting the current structure into some relevant data structure and then apply the required methodology**

Comment: Define "large". Maybe you should use a database instead.

Comment: @str The word list could surpass million

Comment: You can save CPU time but it'll cost memory... like reversing your object to a Map at loading time.

Comment: @RobinCamus Cannot follow this approach

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DB and add proper indexes. But if you really want to stick with this object, you could use [oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/) to avoid parsing the whole document before searching it. It works similar to SAX in the XML world.

See the "Hanging up when we have what we need" example at http://oboejs.com/examples

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the file format to something other than json, maybe you can put each category on a new line like a csv file (without headers) where the first value in a line is the category key

eg:

```
exercise,running,walking,gym........
eat,breakfast,dinner,.......
```

Now, to find the category containing a keyword:

1. search the whole file (with something like grep) and find the lines
   that match
2. Find the first value in each matching line to get the category key